# Data push via Ajax/Post

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxform

I built an PHP/Ajax script to send mass newsletter emails through PHPMailer which works perfectly fine except getting the value from HTML INPUT BOX for the subject of the email.

The table gets the value from MySQL database with the following HTML/Bootstrap;

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                $count = 0;
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                    $count = $count + 1;
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$row["customer_name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["customer_email"].'</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="single_select" class="single_select" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <button type="button" name="email_button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" data-action="single">Send Single</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
                ?>
                
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"></td>
                        <td><button type="button" name="bulk_email" class="btn btn-info email_button" id="bulk_email" data-action="bulk">Send Bulk</button></td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

The following AJAX/POST submits the data to PHP to call PHPMailer function;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.email_button').click(function(){
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var id  = $(this).attr("id");
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        var email_data = [];
        if(action == 'single')
        {
            email_data.push({
                email: $(this).data("email"),
                name: $(this).data("name")
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('.single_select').each(function(){
                if($(this).prop("checked") == true)
                {
                    email_data.push({
                        email: $(this).data("email"),
                        name: $(this).data("name")
                    });
                } 
            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:"send_mail.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{email_data:email_data},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#'+id).html('Sending...');
                $('#'+id).addClass('btn-danger');
            },
            success:function(data){
                if(data == 'ok')
                {
                    $('#'+id).text('Success');
                    $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-danger');
                    $('#'+id).removeClass('btn-info');
                    $('#'+id).addClass('btn-success');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#'+id).text(data);
                }
                $('#'+id).attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })

    });
});
</script>
```

The following PHP Script grabs the data and sends email which works perfectly fine.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST['email_data']))
{
    $output = '';
    foreach($_POST['email_data'] as $row)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->IsSMTP();        
        $mail->XMailer  = "Gleez CMS 0.10.5";   
        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;                    
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
        $mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "password";
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->From = "user@gmail.com";
        $mail->FromName = "Jack N";
        $mail->AddAddress($row["email"], $row["name"]);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "You have a new message";
        $mail->Body = "This line also supports html";

        $mail->AltBody = '';

        $result = $mail->Send();

        if($result["code"] == '400')
        {
            $output .= html_entity_decode($result['full_error']);
        }

    }
    if($output == '')
    {
        echo 'ok';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $output;
    }
}

?>
```

The challenge I face is to replace

```
$mail->Subject = "You have a new message";
```

with

```
$mail->Subject($row["subject"]);
```

The actions I tried was to include the following lines in my HTML page like,

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">

// modify the AJAX Script

subject:$(this).data("subject")
or var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
```

**but none worked!** :(

Any guidance, please? Thank you! Wish y'all a healthy days ahead. Cheers.

Comment: Not sure where you were putting `$(this).data("subject")` but that all depends what `this` is, and whether is has the appropriate `data-subject` attribute.

Comment: `var subject = document.getElementById("subject");` will set the variable to the matching element. You probably want the element's value though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're taking "subject" from the data attribute of $(this), you need to populate the data on the checkbox/button.

So from your current code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="single_select" class="single_select" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" />
<button type="button" name="email_button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" data-action="single">Send Single</button>
```

You need to transform to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="single_select" class="single_select" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" data-subject="'.$row["subject"].'" />
<button type="button" name="email_button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs email_button" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" data-action="single" data-subject="'.$row["subject"].'">Send Single</button>
```

Once you have your data-attributes populated, you will be able to do what you were already doing, using `subject:$(this).data("subject")` to populate this too.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Andrea. Populating data-subject needs to fetch data from database. Any suggestion how to simply get the value of an inputbox and post via ajax to phpmailer? 

My best try was to add an input box with,
`<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject">`
Reading the value with
`var subject = document.getElementById("subject");`
and with ajax
`subject:$(this).data("subject")`

Though; I did not work. 

Any idea?

Comment: You're right on how to get the subject from an Input.

Just the last part should be `subject:subject` or `subject:document.getElementById("subject");` because you're not using $(this). $(this) is actually the button or checkbox

Comment: Didn't work out. Script did not work at all once I tried to read value by getElementId and post 

The code is as follows,

`$('.email_button').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  var id  = $(this).attr("id");
  var action = $(this).data("action");
  var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
  var email_data = [];
  if(action == 'single')
  {
   email_data.push({
    email: $(this).data("email"),
    name: $(this).data("name"),
    subject:subject
   });
  }
  else
  {`

Comment: I have solved my issue with the following,

`$.ajax({
   url:"send_mail.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{email_data:email_data,subject},`

and

`var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;`

Thank you!